# Border-radius and overflow hidden with child background

Tags: css, colors, border, pseudo-element, absolute

I've got a problem with border-radius on wrapper that contains an overflow hidden.

I use a before pseudo element (pink background) to fill the wrapper's background. The wrapper has already a background (blue).

```css
#wrapper {
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
#wrapper::before {
  background: pink;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

With this example, we can see an unwanted blue pixel on the top and bottom left corner.

The pseudo element must be in position absolute to apply animation. I removed the animation for the example.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `:before` element as the blue overlaying element?

Comment: @Roberrrt Yes, it was for the example, here is an other example with transparent background on the button : http://jsfiddle.net/92rxaqh9/5/ 

This is an hover animation on the button an the problem still there.

Comment: This is an anti-alias issue. It's common with border-radius. - https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcss%5danti-alias%20border-radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix is here. Apply `overflow:hidden` an `width:300px` to the outer div `#container`.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 90px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}

#wrapper::before {
  background: pink;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  right: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

#wrapper:hover::before {
  transform: scale3D(10, 10, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your example, it works ! It's too bad to need a container to do that but I think there isn't an other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You found a really interesting rendering issue. My idea to solve it, is switch the colors and logic a little:

```css
#wrapper {
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
#wrapper::before {
  background: blue;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution but in my case, sometimes I have to make the button transparent with animation. So the colors can't be my solution. Example : https://jsfiddle.net/92rxaqh9/5/ In this example, we can see a white border on the top and bottom right corner.